# Jquery animate one after another?

Tags: jquery

im new here and will very much look forward to helping html and css questions. Im new to jquery and my question is this. I would like to animate div1 then div2 then div3 on after another, so far i have this..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div1').animate({top:119},1500, function() {
    $('div2').fadeIn('slow') 
  });
});
```

How and where would I insert `$('div3').fadeIn('slow')` ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.fadeIn()` accepts a callback parameter, just like `.animate()`, so you could do

```
$('#div1').animate({top:119}, 1500, function() {
    $('#div2').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $('#div3').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a callback function for the [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method.  you can add your next fade inside the callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div1').animate({top:119},1500, function() {
    $('div2').fadeIn('slow', function () { 
      $('div3').fadeIn('slow');
    }); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div1').animate({top:119},1500, function() {
$('div2').fadeIn('slow', function() {$('div3').fadeIn('slow')}) 
});
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say it, but you should really considering focusing on readability of your code, so proper spaces behind comma's and indentation, as well as line-breaks. This is pretty hard-to-decipher code for a novice.